Solving an equation involving a unit vector and positive definite matrix
Let $P$ be a (real, symmetric) positive definite matrix and $x$ a unit vector.
Question: Does there exist a unit vector $u$ such that
$$
\frac{x^T(P+I)^{-1} x}{x^T P^{-1} x} = \frac{(u^Tx)^2}{(u^Tx)^2 + x^TP^{-1} x } ~~?
$$
I can see that this holds when $P = p I$ for $p > 0$. Indeed, then we may set $u = x$. Indeed, then it happens that
$$
\frac{(u^Tx)^2}{(u^Tx)^2 + x^TP^{-1} x } = \frac{1}{1 + 1/p} =  
\frac{1/(1+p)}{1/p} = \frac{x^T(P+I)^{-1} x}{x^T P^{-1} x}. 
$$
However, I am not sure what to do for general real symmetric positive definite $P$.

Take $P$ diagonal and write down the equations. Substitute $z=u^Tx$ and solve for $z$. $|z|\le |x|$ iff a solution exists

Am I understanding that what you are suggesting is that the answer is such $u$ exists if and only if $u = \alpha x$ such that $\alpha^2/(\alpha^2 + x^T P^{-1} x) = x^T(P+I)^{-1} x / x^TP^{-1} x$ has a solution for $\alpha \in [-1, 1]$?

No because $u$ must be unit. I am saying that $u^Tx=z$ has a solution iff $|z|\le |x|$

I guess what you can always do, however, is write, without loss of generality that $u_\alpha = \alpha x + (1 - \alpha^2)^{1/2} y$ where $y$ lies in the orthogonal perp of $x$ with unit norm. In particular, the equation does not depend on $y$, so it seems we can solve the above equation in $\alpha^2$, and then pick any $y$ orthogonal to $z$ and plug it into the equation for $u_\alpha$?
